# Does squid ink pasta bleed?

Tags: pasta, color, squid

Will the black color from squid ink spaghetti bleed onto other ingredients?

I was recently given a package of squid ink spaghetti. I haven't used it before and I want to try something creative.

I was thinking of separately cooking some regular spaghetti and mixing the white and black together after they are cooked separately. This won't look good if the black bleeds onto the white. It would just turn everything gray.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, as far as I know pasta made with squid ink, often called *nero di seppia*, should be stable, and the ink doesn't normally bleed.

From my experience after boiling black pasta, even the fresh kind, the water comes out clear like with regular one, with just a bit of clear maybe slightly grayish starch being left behind.

If you boil regular and black pasta mixed together the white pasta should not get significantly tainted with black color, just like when you boil *tricolore* type of colored pasta (those multi colored green, red and white mixes) the colors don't bleed.

You can (briefly) see [in this cooking video](https://youtu.be/A7iOBZZfsrA?t=678) that neither the boiling water nor the rinsing water are darkened.

Black ink also doesn't bleed into sauces after boiling, so you can use light colored sauces without negatively affecting it's appearance, nor does it stain containers like the white ceramic of dishes, bowls or plastics.

Only situation where you should get bleeding black is for dishes where the squid ink is added to the pasta after boiling, either while stirring in the sauce or along with other ingredients, rather than being mixed into the flour.

Answer (score 5):

I have cooked squid ink pasta, and did not find much bleeding.  On the other hand, i’ve had SIP in a restaurant, and everything was stained black.  So perhaps there’s some other variable at play.

Comment: Hrm, so maybe it varies from SIP to SIP -- maybe OP should just boil a couple of noodles and find out.

Comment: As per Duarte's answer, maybe the restaurant added the squid ink, rather than it being integrated into the pasta as the pasta was made?

Comment: On the few occasions that I cooked it (I don't like the flavour, so I don't eat it much) the water did come out noticeably coloured, though not nearly opaque. And the pasta did not stain the rest of the food. I think the real answer is, YMMV.